# For a web app, what's the best way to ensure users get the latest code (avoiding cache issues)?

Tags: caching, web, web-applications, versioning, browser-cache

There have been cases where things are getting cached and users have to manually clear the cache in order to use the latest version of the app. What's the best strategy for dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole bunch of [HTTP headers which deal with caching behaviour](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/).

Configuring this correctly is possibly more an art than a science - without any caching, your site will feel very slow to end users, and you'll have to deal with a LOT of traffic to your site.

However, with aggressive caching, you may end up serving stale content, or old versions of your JavaScript and CSS.

A common solution to this is to use eTags and "modifiedSince" requests - this means the browser will check whether a resource in the cache is out of date by asking the server if it has a newer version, and only download the new version if it needs to.